# Homogeneous functions (Banach)

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

I am reading a textbook (on sectorial operators) and the author mentions that for a real Banach space $X$, the function $\phi:X\times X\rightarrow \mathbb{R};\phi(x_1,x_2)=(\|x_1\|^2+\|x_2\|^2)^{1/2}$, is, in general, not homogeneous. However we see that 
$$
\phi(tx_1,tx_2)=t^1\phi(x_1,x_2).
$$

What does the author mean?

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say, that $\phi$ is only positively homogeneous, but to give a more informed answer, the name of the book and the author would be quite a help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $\phi(tx_1,tx_2)=t\phi(x_1,x_2)$ only in the case $t \ge 0$.

In general we have

$\phi(tx_1,tx_2)=|t|\phi(x_1,x_2)$